# splitting tasks to categories

Tags: c++, algorithm, design-patterns

I have a class (lets call it checker) and diffrent kind of classes that execute tasks (lets call them tasks). each tasks belongs to several categories

each task runs and at some point asks checker if they are allowed to do something. checker answers according to system state and according to their category. a task can be in multiple categories

how would you implement that? (cpp but I don't really think its language specific).

I was thinking adding a list of  categories in each task and have a function that gets a category and answers if the task belongs to it.

```
class checker {
    bool is_allowed(Task * task);
}

class Task
{
    bool is_belongging_to_category(Category cat);
    void some_task_to_do()
    {
        ...
        if (checker::is_allowed(this)) { ....}
        else {....}
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to solve this? Maybe some known design pattern...

Comment: I suspect you'll need to give more detail... is the `is_allowed()` check meant to be "am I allowed to do _this specific thing_" (i.e. some kind of "permissions" model), because if so, what you've shown doesn't have any indication of what it is that the task is asking about.  Alternatively, is it a generic "am I allowed to do some work [of any kind]" (i.e. more of a "load-balancing" model)? If the latter, there probably should be some while/sleep looping, or other scheduling mechanism.

Comment: is_allowed is a permission mechanisem. I did not want to complicate things, but this is part of a much larger system and the tasks are the way to paralelize work. for example a task may want to save its config to disk but that is not allowed if the system is during shutdown (unless this task is part  of the shutdown)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like questionable design. You're making tasks the objects.

Let's say your tasks are: *Eat*, *Drink*, and *Be_Merry*

If you make each of those tasks objects, they'll have to maintain a reference to the actual individual that they operate on, then when the condition is met they'll need to modify state on the given individual.

This is a violation of [Object Oriented Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_design#Object-oriented_concepts) which defines an object as:

> A tight coupling or association of data structures with the methods or functions that act on the data

Notice that you have split the "methods or functions that act on the data" from the object. Instead you should have modeled the objects *Jack* and *Jill* which had **methods**: *Eat*, *Drink*, and *BeMerry*

As far as `checker`, whether it's parceled out will depend upon whether you're using a [push](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) or a [pull coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull_technology). If you're doing push coding, then checker is simply a holding area for the behavioral properties of *Jack* and *Jill*, in such a case the properties should be pushed to *Jack* and *Jill* rather than held in `checker`. If they are properties for all *Jack* or *Jill* objects, use a `static` property. If however you are using pull coding then the information is unavailable until you attempt to execute the task. In this case the `checker` should probably be a singleton that *Jack* and *Jill* access in the process of performing their tasks.

**EDIT:**

[Your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41467518/splitting-tasks-to-categories/41468137?noredirect=1#comment70168599_41468137) reveals further tragedy in the design. It seems as though you've kicked off a bunch of threads which are doing busy waiting on `checker`. This indicates that you need to be using a pull coding. You're *Jack* and *Jill* objects need to maintain booleans for which tasks they are actively involved in, for example `m_is_going_to_school`, then when `checker` gets the condition that would stop your busy waiting in your design, instead kick off the `goToSchool` method.

Comment: The Task object does have a method, and what would set these m_canEat etc other than a call to a Boolean function as in the question?There may be cases when can should be pushed rather than queried but you can't assert that from the information in the question - it might be entirely appropriate to "reach out to an external checker"

Comment: @ROX "What would set these m_canEat etc other than a call to a Boolean function as in the question?" Rather than separating information about how a *Jack* or *Jill* should function into those objects and `checker` you would store it within *Jack* or *Jill*, if the boolean governs the behavior of all such objects feel free to make it a static member. As far as the case of a pull system, you're right, so I'll edit.

Comment: technically speaking you are correct (and I gave you a +1), but this is part of a large system and the task classes are the way to parallelize long tasks. for example jill might have a task "go to school" which is long and built of a few sub phases. so in this implemintation there will be a go_to_school task that has a pointer to jill and that task is executed in a parallel mechanizem the system manages.

Comment: @Jonathan Mee. Yes, the edit makes more sense to me. I didn't mean to imply there were no cases where what you had said was correct, just that it did not apply in all cases.

Comment: @Epic From what you've explained so far you've got a bad design that is forcing busy waiting on you. This is a common malady of push coding. I've tried to outline how you can free yourself from that by improving the design. I've also given you a +1.

Comment: in your implementation, how does checker knows which function to call to? you do not want every change to the system, jack, jill to update checker so it would go to jack and jill and check which tasks are needed and call their functions

Comment: @Epic It'd have to be the same way that the `checker` is already working. Somehow it knows whether to return true or false, when just a pointer to the task is passed to it. Such logic would have to persist for individual *Jack* and *Jill* objects. Simply by being passed an object pointer `checker` would know how to respond.

Comment: @Jonathan Mee, checker can tell you jack is allowed to walk, that does not mean jack should walk...

Comment: @Epic Right, so in your current setup you have busy waiting tasks, which are consuming CPU resources while they wait for checker to tell them to go. Now you'd simply set a flag on the object that *Jack* is ready to walk, when checker subsequently get's the info that *Jack* is go it will ask whatever your main entity for all *Jacks* find the one or ones which it has just been notified are eligible for walking and call their appropriate method. Note that there is no busy waiting in this system.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a vector to store all the possible allowed options. You can make a bool function (like you have) called IsAllowed with argument string and that will check if the option its going to do is allowed. If not, return false. That's just my idea though. Of course there's a zillion different ways to implement this. If you want multiple choices. Then you can make a 2d vector, and see if the corresponding row has any of the options. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the maximum number of categories in advance, I'd recommend using Bit Flags to do this.

```
enum Category {
    CATEGORY_A = 1,
    CATEGORY_B = 1 << 1,
    CATEGORY_C = 1 << 2,
    CATEGORY_D = 1 << 3,
};

class Task {
  int32_t categories_;
public:
  Task() : categories_(0) {}

  void add_category(Category cat) {
    categories_ |= cat;
  }

  void run() {
    checker::can_run(categories_);
  }
}
```

This allows to test for multiple categories all at once:

```
namespace checker {

bool can_run(int32_t categories) {
  int32_t cannot_run_right_now = CATEGORY_A | CATEGORY_C;   

  if(categories & cannot_run_right_now != 0) {
     return false;
  }
  ...
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends. If you are 100% sure that you know how many categories there are to be and that is not some gigantic number then you might store this information as an integer. If n-th bit is 1 then task belongs to n-th category. Then depends on the state of system you might create some another integer that would serve as a mask. In the end you would just do some bit-AND ( mask & categories != 0 ) operation to determine if task and mask share common bit.

On the other hand if there will be unknown number of categories you might just make a list of categories it belongs to. Make a dictionary of [SYSTEM_STATE] => [CATEGORIES_AVAILABLE] and check

```
  bool is_allowed(Task * task){
    foreach (Category sysC in stateCategories[sys.GetState()])
    {
       foreach (Category taskC in task.GetCategories()) 
       {
         if(sysC == taskC) return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
    }
```

That would of course be slow for a big number of categories.
You could improve this method by making this list of categories some another data structure, in which searching is not O(n) such that the code would look like this :

```
  bool is_allowed(Task * task){
    foreach (Category sysC in stateCategories[sys.GetState()])
    {
       if task.GetCategories().Contains(sysC) {
         return true;
       }
    }
```

It depends